# php: pdo read clob without bind

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, clob, oracle-call-interface

```
$query = "select id, xmldata from xmlcontent where id = '586655' OR id = '671347'"

$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
```

output:

```
...
["XMLDATA"]=> resource(33) of type (stream)
...
```

how i can read this? i try:

```
stream_get_contents()
```

but nothing

with

```
stream_get_contents()
```

sometimes read some litle text, i  would like to use and generic code from all SQL-s without binding params :(

Comment: What happens if you call [`stream_get_meta_data`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) on the resource?  You should get an array with useful information.

Comment: i will try on monday when i come back to work thank you :)

Comment: Array
(
    [stream_type] => pdo_oci blob stream
    [mode] => r+b
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] => 
    [timed_out] => 
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] => 
) @Charles

Comment: So, it's read-only, not seekable, not eof, and *is* blocked.  That's odd.  Unfortunately I have no suggestions...

Comment: Out of curiousity, are You using Oracle database?

Comment: Rauni yes i'm using oracle database

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to read twice from the same stream or just using old pdo_oci library with a bug (only last stream will be returned on multiple records).

For the last version, compiled from php source on Ubuntu server i just use lazy-load in `ActiveRecord` class:

```
public function getFullText()
{
    if (is_resource($this->fulltext)) {
        $this->fulltext = stream_get_contents($this->fulltext);
    }
    return $this->fulltext;
}
```

Where `fulltext` is `CLOB`.

Comment: PDO_OCI is deprecated and i can compile it to probe it :(

Comment: It's deprecated? I thought it was just abandoned as stand-alone extension due to built-in version into PHP itself?

Comment: there is no oracle pdo extension for php in the repos

Comment: It was built into PHP itself.

Comment: in gnu/linux? documentation to install it?

Comment: [Best answer i've found](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31965856/350980) You'll face a lot of problems with Oracle and PDO_OCI, though. For example, BLOB's and CLOB's. I managed to solve most of them for now, but it was not obvious problems.